# Stop WordPress from enclosing script in CDATA

Tags: html, wordpress, xhtml, cdata

I am importing HTML pages using HTML import plugin for WordPress.

I have a code snippet for google maps, which is imported.

However, after import, it encloses the `script` tag in `CDATA`. If I remove CDATA, the map works fine. How do I stop WordPress from enclosing the script with CDATA?

Here's the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <[[CDATA[
      var locations = [ ['<strong>Alabama', 33.606379, -86.50249, 1] ];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.606379, -86.50249),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var marker, i;
      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, click, (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  ]]>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
```

wp-includes\post-template.php line 167

Comment: should I comment this line ? This is adding closing brackets , where are opening brackets being added ?

Comment: Thanks for the help Badri , I found the solution on line 167 by changing code to this : 

wp-includes\post-template.php line 167

    $content = str_replace('<![CDATA[','',$content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>','',$content);
 //$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

Comment: Mhh, sorry for my minimalist answer, I thought I wrote it more clear. Don't forget to change it every time you upgrade Wordpress. Or write it somehow to your functions.php theme file.

Comment: Ugh. Don't *ever* overwrite WP core files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do in this way in template page file:

```
   <?php $content = str_replace(']]&gt;', ']]>', the_content()); echo $content; ?>
```

Comment: The above is mistake.
 $content = str_replace(']]&gt;', ']]>', the_content()); echo $content;

Comment: if it's a mistake, click on `edit` below the post to correct the mistake. [help]