# Keep wordpress from adding CDATA

Tags: html, wordpress, xhtml, cdata

I'm too new to be able to comment on the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492472/stop-wordpress-from-using-cdata).

I'm trying to post source code and wp keeps adding CDATA et al to the code, causing it to not display correctly.

I changed wp-includes\post-template.php line 167 to this, as per the answer I found.

```
$content = str_replace('<![CDATA[','',$content); $content = str_replace(']]>','',$content); //$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
```

After amending that line, I'm still experiencing wp changing code around. Is there something else I can do to keep wp from messing things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much as I hate answering with 'use a plugin' on SO there's a few plugins that allow you to add code via a shortcode.  I use an old one called Qoate on my blog (still works fine on 3.4);

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qoate-simple-code-snippets/

A quick Google gives this one too;

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/

Save yourself a load of hassle trying to set it all up and format it yourself (concentrate on writing the code to be displayed rather than the code to display it! :) )

Answer (score 3):

Old post but this is how I fixed it... Try throwing this code into a plugin or your functions.php file.

```
function remove_bad_things(){ ?>
<script>

jQuery('#content-html').click(function(){
  jQuery('textarea[name=content]').val( jQuery('textarea[name=content]').val().replace('// <![CDATA[','') );
  jQuery('textarea[name=content]').val( jQuery('textarea[name=content]').val().replace('// ]]>','') );
});

</script>
<?php }

add_action('admin_footer','remove_bad_things');
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering out these tags on saving posts did the trick for me:

```
function my_filter_cdata( $content ) {
  $content = str_replace( '// <![CDATA[', '', $content );
  $content = str_replace( '// ]]>', '', $content );
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'my_filter_cdata', 9, 1 );
```